# Two dual DVI cards, but six outputs?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

I have two NVIDIA GeForce 9800 GT video cards. They run two monitors each:

[image]

But when I press the "Detect" button, I get this:

[image]

Is that an extra output per card? How do I make that work, by getting a DVI Y-adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain on this, and correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the 9800 GT has the ability to display on 2 monitors at once - either 2xDVI or 1xDVI + 1xHDMI

You have 3 monitor connections, but only 2 of them can be used at any one time.

Comment: you are correct, but that has nothing to do with the "Another display not detected" box.

Comment: I think the 2 "Another display not detected" boxes may be the TV outputs which would be detected if you had TVs attached to them.  It probably wouldn't let you activate them unless you de-activated another display on each card first.

Answer (score 1):

The third connector is a [S-Video](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/S-Video) connector, you can activate it by connecting a S-video cable. Although I believe the 9xxx series cards are only capable of driving two displays per GPU. I can confirm this is the case with the 7950GT as well as the 8800GT I should have a 9800gt laying around to test 3 displays if you want.

EDIT: Matt Jenkins points out (below) that it is not actually S-video, it is mini-DIN which are fully compatible with S-video, they just provide increase functionality:

> This is a non standard 7-pin mini-DIN
>   connectors (this variant is called
>   "7P"). These are used on computer
>   equipment (PCs). A 7-pin socket
>   accepts and is pin compatible with
>   standard 4-pin S-video plug.[5] The
>   three extra may be used to supply
>   composite (CVBS) or an RGB or YPbPr
>   video signal, or an I²C interface. The
>   pin out usage varies between
>   manufacturers.[5] In some
>   implementations, the remaining pin
>   needs to be grounded to enable the
>   composite output (or disable the
>   S-video output on some of those
>   implementations).

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly a third output on the card:

[image]

However I can't find anything on the site that indicates what it might be - it looks like it could be S-Video but (as Matt points out) is actually a 7 pin mini DIN socket.

Comment: It can't be the HDMI - it's not got enough pins.  I think it connects via an adaptor to a composite or s-video input?

Comment: @Matt - I didn't think it was HDMI either, but you never know. It does look like S-Video.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Video#7-pin_mini-DIN